Azure Devops - where to find the "Team Automation Rules"
According to Microsoft Release Notes, there's a new feature that should be available as of Sprint 233 in Azure Devops:

Team Automation Rules is generally available
We're happy to announce the release of this feature to all customers of Azure DevOps Service.
You can now configure each backlog level to automate the opening and closing (or resolving) of work items based on the state of the child items. There are two main scenarios we're attempting to solve.

When a single child item is activated, then activate the parent.
When all child items are closed, then close the parent (or resolve it).

To enable these settings, click on the backlog level configuration for your team. Then go to the Automation > Rules tab to see the two different rules you can apply to your backlog. Each backlog level (requirements, features, epics) can be configured differently depending on how your team wants to work.

We're currently on Sprint 236 of Azure Devops - so this should definitely be available to us (and would be most welcome!) - alas, I cannot seem to find this "Team Settings" and "Automation" tab anywhere.....
Can someone provide an illustrated explanation as to where to find these settings so I can turn this feature on?
Update: @brightran-msft
This is what I see when I go to the "Settings" in "Boards > Backlog":

No sign of "Automation > Rules" anywhere .....

At first, ensure you have turn on "New Boards Hubs".
You should go to Boards > Backlogs tab, open the Backlog page of your team, then click "Configure team settings" to open "Team Settings" window. On the "Team Settings" window, you can configure Automation Rules.


That's what I thought, too - but unfortunately - I don't see this "Automation - Rules" part ......

@marc_s, At first, ensure you have turn on "New Boards Hubs".

AHA !!! That was the key - turning on the "New Boards Hub" feature - THEN that "Automation > Rules" feature shows up !

Funny enough - in one particular project, where we made a few changes to the Process template, it doesn't work. Any idea why? Anything I can check and look for?
